# VS-Code won't pause debugger on exception inside Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, promise, visual-studio-code

Please consider the following code:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   breaksomething() //won't pause
})
breaksomething() //pause as expected!
```

I am expecting my debugger to halt execution - because of an undefined function - at the line `breaksomething()` inside the `promise`... However I am only getting the following error output:

> "ReferenceError: breaksomething is not defined"

(without pausing). Everywhere else the debugger is pausing as expected when an exception is encountered, the problem is only inside a Promise scope. I do have both *All Exceptions* and *Uncaught Exceptions* ticked under breakpoints.

I am using:
Visual Studio Code 1.17.2
Node 8.8.1
Inspector debugger

Comment: Where are you adding definition for `breaksomething()`?

Comment: There is no definition - I want to create an exception.

Comment: Seems like this happens because Promise is implemented in a native library and the calling happens of the function happens from that native library. The exception is send back there and hence not caught by VSC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still unclear why this issue is happening but I found a workaround.  Just install bluebird and add the following in the initialisation code of your app:

```
global.Promise = require("bluebird");
```

...this will override the default nodejs Promise and break as expected when "All exceptions" is ticked

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**
Per [latest update on a known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1746#issuecomment-293304364) from Microsoft team it was a known issue in VS code.

You have to UNCHECK `All Exceptions` and `Uncaught Exceptions` in breakpoints settings in VS code in order for that to work

[image: debugger works without exceptions]

Comment: This is incorrect.
1) The link does not point out any issue in VS Code - its simply an explanation on how NOT to break on exceptions
2) The image you attached has a breakpoint.  Breakpoints gets hit and execution halted for regardless of Exceptions tickmarks.

Comment: @Pierre as of today it is the only solution i was able to find for your problem.

Comment: What don't you get about the question - this is not a solution! You are showing me how to halt the debugger on a breakpoint!  That is not the problem - the problem is to halt the debugger on an exception.

Answer (score 4):

After debugging I found that this is happening because Promise library is implement in Native code

So when you create a Promise, the function inside is actually called by the Native code and the exception goes back to it. This might be one of the reasons that it is not caught by VS debugger.

Is it impossible to do so? Well WebStorm from JetBrains is able to break on such exceptions also. Now how they do it and why VS Code is not able to do it, is beyond my understanding. It would be best to open a issue against VS code and refer that WebStorm does it. So it is technically possible to break on such exceptions

Comment: This doesn't sound correct to me, but if you want to try - try it with bluebird. I want to point out that I've successfully debugged from vscode before (but I don't know what's causing your issue or how to solve it, sorry).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, its not about debugging issue. It is about automatic breakpoint on exceptions